# Apache .htaccess 2 directions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to get a .htaccess set when the apache would use the index.php if the first condition matches and would use the index.html if the second.

I was trying like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/anystring.*
RewriteRule . index.php

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/anystring
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.html
```

So if the request uri start with anystring then index.php, otherwise index.html.

The code above doesnt work like that, whats wrong with it?

Comment: And what is your actual question? You posted a code but failed to tell us what is wrong, what does not work as expected. Please revise your question, add information so that we can help. Do _not_ post additional information in comments here. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it._

Comment: By `anystring` do you mean "All files and directories" which exist on your server or just 404 URIs?

Comment: I want this: if not an existing file or dir. and starts with a literal, then index.php, otherwise index.html. The "anystring" just an example, could be foo or bar or any string.

Comment: So you want to point your existing  files and dirs to `/index.html` ..and all other non-existent requests to `/index.php` ..right?

Comment: No, I dont want to point existing files and dirs, I want them to be ignored by the rewrite engine. And so I want the non-existent requests would point to index.php or index.html, depending if that non-existent request starts with a string or not. If starts then point ot the index.php, if not then point to the index.html.

Comment: OK . Then the rules you posed in your question  should work. What problems are you having with these rules?

Comment: Actually it works but need to do force refresh in the browser like CTRL+F5, otherwise the browser gets confused and doesn't work. Maybe its some browser caching issue at all. Do you have idea for that?